Maximum element at index K of array with constraints
I've been trying to complete a programming practice question for a couple hours now, but can't seem to make any headway.
The question is the following:
Given an array and the following constraints:

The array consists of $N$ positive integers
The sum of all the elements in the array is at most $M$
The absolute difference between any two consecutive elements in the array is at most $1$

What is the maximum value of the integer at index $K$ in such an array?
My thinking so far was that this array, could be thought of as a "hill" which has it's maximum value at $K$. So say the value at index $K$ is $x$, then the value at $K-1$ and $K+1$ being $x-1$ and so on until the end of either side of the array. This let me decompose the sum of the array into:
$M = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{K}x-i\right) + x + \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-K-1}x-i\right)$
$x = \frac{M + \frac{K(K+1)}{2} + \frac{(N-K-1)(N-K)}{2}}{N}$
But the issue is that this doesn't account for the case where X is less than the distance to either the start or end of the array, and so it calculates as if there were negative values. I'm not sure how to account for that in $x$, help would be greatly appreciated!
